# VSCode Prettier formats HTML in an odd way (greater-than-symbol on next line)

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Since today VSCode with installed Prettier Extension formats my HTML in a really odd way. For example:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-secondary mr-2"
  (click)="updateEditState(EditState.preview)"
  *ngIf="!(preview | async)"
>
  <ng-container i18n="AppPreviewEditButton|Enables the Preview mode of the page@@AppPreviewButton"
    >Preview</ng-container
  >
</button>
<button class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" (click)="updateEditState(EditState.edit)" *ngIf="!(edit | async)">
  <ng-container i18n="AppPreviewEditButton|Enables the Edit mode of the page@@AppEditButton"
    >Edit</ng-container
  >
</button>
```

Notice the `>` on new lines. Did somebody else experienced the same and has a solution?

Comment: Could it be the [JSX Brackets option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)?

Comment: Seems like thats the option for it, but enabling it does not change the format.Might be a bug then.

Comment: Opened an Issue here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the issue finally got resolved:
You can now use [`bracketSameLine: true`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line) in the prettier settings to control the behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

You should set `"htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"` in your project's .prettierrc file.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Go to **VS Code settings** by pressing **CTR + ,** or from the menu **File > Preferences > Settings**

type **prettier** in the search settings and check **Bracket Same Line** checkbox as shown blow.

[image]